# array-element-newline: combining "consistent" and "multiline"

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint

I'm looking to configure my ESLint rules such that:

- newlines between array elements must be *consistent*, i.e. if there's a newline between any two array elements, then there should be a newline between every array element,
- if there's a newline inside any of the array's elements, then there should be a newline between every array element.

The problem that I have is that the `array-element-newline` rule cannot be configured like that. Either you go with the `consistent` option, in which case you cannot guarantee that there won't be code like such:

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    key: 'value'
  }, { // <- ew.
    key: 'value'
  }
];
```

Or, you go with the `{ multiline: true}` option, which solves the above but disallows something like:

```js
const myArray = [
  A,
  Long,
  List,
  Of,
  Stuff,
  For,
  Example,
  Angular,
  Modules
];
```

Do I really have to write an ESLint plugin to achieve what I want?

Comment: When you saw ew, I say "nice"

Comment: I do not think there are any rules for that target arrays and the bracket without effecting all of the brackets. multiline supports min, I think

Comment: I'll probably end up combining `multiline` and `minItems`. It's annoying though.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with this combo? (change minItems as you want):

```
"array-element-newline": ["error", { "multiline": true, "minItems": 5 }],
"array-bracket-newline": ["error", { "minItems": 5}],
```

This defines when to move elements in a new line but also when to move the bracket to a new line.

This is the result:
[image]